# Interactive equidistant map for HAM radio application

Tags: coordinate-system, web-mapping, software-recommendations, html

Our local HAM Radio Club is currently using a Google Map for our rotor direction visualization software, here is an example of our app: https://linkpaste.org/visu/

[image]

Now - for obvious reasons - I want to change the projection of the map to an azimuthal equidistant one but have struggled a lot trying to implement a different projection on Google Maps... (tried with proj4, no luck, the official documentation only provides some code for a Gall-Peters Projection: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-projection-simple)

I am willing to switch to some other library/software (mapnik, leaflet.js, OpenLayers...)

This is what I need

1. The map should be *interactive* (zoomable, can drag around, etc.)
2. The map should have a *fixed center which I can define* (our current position)
3. The projection must be *equidistant*
4. The map should have *basic names* for countries, cities, etc.

I have found NS6T's [Equidistant Azimuth Map generator](https://ns6t.net/azimuth/), but I need an interactive map not just a background image or PDF...

I also found [this tool](http://maps.ontarget.cc/azmap/en.html) which kind of illustrates what I need, but it lacks any country or city names, it's just a basic shape of Europe.

Basically, something like a normal Google Map or Open Street Maps, but with Equidistant projection, would be ideal.

Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: d3.js has support for azimuthal equidistant example  https://riptutorial.com/d3-js/example/28667/azimuthal-equidistant-projections

Comment: Since Leaflet cannot do on the fly reprojection of raster maps, the next simplest solution would be OpenLayers + proj4.js + Open Street Map.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs, will check out d3.js and OL+proj4.js